# Full Network Paths In QGIS

Tags: qgis, file-path

Is it possible to use full network paths in QGIS rather than relative paths or drive paths?  I use a remote desktop connection to log in to a machine where some QGIS work is done, however when ting to open these projects on my local machine, I get the "handle bad layers" message due to the file paths being different for layers stored on different network drives. people map these drives to different letters around the different offices so to use the full network address in the file paths would get around this issue hopefully.

Comment: Try to put qgis project file and layers to the same network drive and use relative path in the project file.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the project to use absolute paths under the General tab of the Project options.

Comment: Unfortunately using the absolute path rather than relative path will give the drive letter of that computer as opposed to the network address so it will not open on a different computer on the same network. I'm not sure it is possible, but thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Dragging layers from a network address in Windows Explorer uses the network address rather than a drive letter.  If you want to drag layers from the QGIS Browser, then it isn't so obvious how to add the network path.

Go to Project Properties, and under General Settings select the network path for Project home.

[image]

Then in the Browser, the Project Home folder becomes visible.  Right click on any of the sub folders and you can add them to Favorites.  You can then browse using full network addresses. Favorites seems to be independent of the project, so it will stay here until you remove it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did not try this but I think you could  open your .qgs in a text editor and replace the drive path with the full network path.

This should work but it's possible that your change will be overwrite when the project is saved again....

Comment: I just try It and it does work